# Mysql Help Needed

Tags: mysql

I have a table named group Info. It has three fields namely id,user_id, and group_id.
My question is how to assign unique users to a group i-e same user may not be repeated in a same group.
Table structure for group Info is as follows;

```
id         int(11)  Auto increment,Primary key NOT NULL,

user_id    int(11)  Not Null,

group_id   int(11)  Not Null
```

I have made the user_id unique.But there are two groups(2 group_id(1 and 2)).Selecting users for groupB gives error duplicate entry.
user_id = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8;
group_id= 1,2;

Kindly help me how to solve this.Iam not good in english so apologies for my language.

Comment: as per your question, one user should be associated with a unique group. here 1-1 relation between group_id and user_id. Group_id should also be unique. So you delete the duplicate records assigned for groupB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl_name` ADD UNIQUE (
`col1` ,
`col2`
);
```

Change col1 with user_id and col2 with group_id and tbl_name with your table name.

Answer (score 0):

If `user_id` is unique, then you probably shouldn't be creating a join table:   just add a group pointer to the user table.

If, on the other hand, a user can belong to more than one group, then your current design is probably appropriate, but you shouldn't make `user_id` unique (although you might want to make a unique **composite key** on the *combination* of `user_id` *and* `group_id`).

Comment: sir users table contains registered users.After registration I am assigning them groups. I am getting users list from users table and assigning them groups which i have stored in groups table.After assigning i am storing it in group Info table have the described above three fields.Now If I dont keep the user_id unique,then same user can be assaigned to a group twice which I dont want?

Comment: @muhammadmaaz  Read my answer again (especially the part about the **composite key**):  I answered precisely the question you're asking.